# Would a characters font change depending on font avaiablity?

Tags: html, css

So have a problem achieving some special uni-code characters to display across multiple users computers. My implemented font-stack is as follows:

```
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
```

Now say for some odd reason a user doesn't have the letter "A" installed for 'Georgia' would the letter "A" change to "Times New Roman" instead?

Comment: Why not just try it out for yourself? You can check with the character map which characters are defined in both fonts, then choose a character that doesn't exist in one font but does in the other, and see what happens!

Comment: @MrLister That's the problem I'm having! If I'm missing a certain Unicode in Georgia it still somehow renders within my browser

Comment: Yes. Then try a different font in the second position in your font-family, say a sans-serif font, and see the the rendering changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the specifications, absolutely. In browser practice, mostly, but far from always.

The CSS 2.1 specification clearly prescribes an algorithm where the font family list is scanned, when necessary, at the character level. The section [Font matching algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#algorithm) says: “2. At a given element and for each character in that element, the UA assembles the font properties applicable to that element. – – If there is a matching font face, but it does not contain a glyph for the current character, and if there is a next alternative 'font-family' in the font sets, then repeat step 2 with the next alternative 'font-family'.”

One reason why this may fail is that browsers rely on information in the font files about their character coverage, instead of inspecting the font file contents in detail. In the hypothetical case present, a browser would check that Georgia announces to cover the Basic Latin range, among other things. And it would thus delegate it to Georgia to render “A”. If the font has been deprived of the glyph for “A”, by some black magic, then the rendering would fail in some manner.

That’s not probable, but it is possible that a font announces to support a Unicode range but does not cover all the *new* characters added to that range since the font was last updated.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Font faces are resolved as "does this font exist" and not "is this font complete". It's faster and more consistent that way - plus, doesn't cause your text to look like it's been cut out of a newspaper.

Your best bet is to look at the glyphs the fonts supply and pick one that has all the glyphs you want. As a not-as-good-but-perhaps-ok option, if you don't like those fonts (and there are only a few that have e.g. Japanese Kanji or Farsi glyphs), you could perhaps manage the font stack on the server side by providing a different font-family based on the language.

Comment: I've tested this in Firefox and Chrome. In each case, if there is no entry for a character in the first font in a font-family,it uses the next font in the css declaration for that. If there is no next font, it will inherit the font of the first parent with a definition, going up the tree,

Answer (score 0):

No, I think for characters which are missing, the site would return a `□` kind of symbol depicting that the character isn't available.

Only if the actual font face itself is not on the system, does the system then switch to the next in line on the `font-family`.

Comment: If the character IS NOT available it does not always display a □